# What does this line in array mean?

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist

```
    int greatest = list.get(0);

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            int number = list.get(i);

            if (greatest < number) {
                greatest = number;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The greatest number: " + greatest);
```

```
if (greatest < number) {
    greatest = number;
}
```

I don't understand how these two codes work and how it finds the greatest number. Let's say the example is 2,5,3,4,1. Then "greatest" is list.get(0) which is the first number which would be 2 from example. Then, "number" is list.get(i) which is the array list itself. How is 2 < 4 then become 2 = 4 finds the greatest number? Stuck on these two lines for a long time. Would appreciate someone helping out. Thanks!

Comment: It iterates over the array, compares every element in the array with the value it currently has saved as `greatest` and if the element in the array is larger than `greatest` it will set `greatest` to that value. So in your example, it `greatest` will first be `2`. Then it will compare `greatest=2` to `5`, see that `5` is bigger and set `greatest=5`. Then it will compare `greatest=5` to `3`, see that it is smaller and do nothing...and that will continue until the iteration is done.

Comment: If greatest has the value 2, number 4, then greatest gets assigned a new value 4. So `=` can be pronounced as **becomes**. An other language like Pascal would have written `greatest := number;`

Comment: Just imagine you were that program: you have a bucket with numbers and blindly pull one (the first). This is your greatest number... so far. Then you pull numbers one-by-one until the bucket is empty (you reached the end of the array). You compare each number you just pulled with the number you hold in your other hand (the greatest so far). If the number you just pulled is greater (or the number you hold is smaller) you throw away the number you held and keep the one you just pulled. When the bucket is empty the number you have in your hand is the greatest of all. :)

Answer (score 0):

The line `greatest = number;` doesn't compare the values. It assigns the value of number to the variable `greatest`. So you have to read the line like `greatest = 4;`.